# Saving data when using JPA and BeansBinding

Tags: java, swing, jpa, desktop, beans-binding

I am currently experimenting with JPA in a desktop application, while using BeansBinding to make the GUI development easier. So far the results are quite good.

As an example application I have a small DB with only one table. I successfully created the entity, the PU. Next I dropped a JTable into the main JFrame and bound it's columns to a JPA query. This works like a charm. So, changes made to the entities reflect in the table, and vice-versa.

Next I wanted to make the table editable, such that the changes are persisted into the DB. The easiest way I came up with was to begin a query and immediately commit it. So, assuming I had a JButton somewhere, do the following on `actionPerformed`:

```
private void saveClicked(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    this.myEntityManager.getTransaction().begin();
    this.myEntityManager.getTransaction().commit();
}
```

This works perfectly but it looks oddly wrong to me. I also tried to do this on `windowClosing`. With success.

But why is it that this worked? I mean, there is no code whatsoever between the transaction `begin` and `commit`. And more importantly, is it O.K. to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This somewhat erratic behavior, where the **entitymanager** persists uncommitted changes without explicitly being told so, arrises because application-manged entity managers are always extended. The JPA specification (in section 3.3) says:

> The scope of the persistence context
>   of an application-managed entity
>   manager is extended. It is the
>   responsibility of the application to
>   manage the lifecycle of the
>   persistence context.

So when the bean in question is already in persistence context and you perform a **transaction.commit** any uncommitted changes will be persisted even without a explicit **entitymanager.persist**. You can verify this behavior for yourself by clearing the entitymanager (**entitymanager.clear**) prior to committing the transaction. This will remove the entity from the tx-commit and will cause the transaction to perform no changes to the database.

Comment: oops... totally forgot to accept this one... :) Better late than never :)